# Using results of one query as a combined set of conditions to run another query on the same table

Tags: sql, subquery, common-table-expression, with-statement

I am trying to run a query to do the following; all of the information will be contained in the same table.

For a specified product of interest find the price of the product and the country it is sold in. The result of this query should produce a set of countries and a set of prices that correspond to the sales price of that product in each country (the prices will differ across countries).

For example, the result of this query may reveal that the product is sold in India for 100$ and Russia for 200$.
(In advance of running this query, we did not know the product was sold in these countries or the prices)

The results of that query, should then be used as a joined set of conditions to pull other parameters of interest from the table as per another query. The results of this query is the ultimate outcome we hope to achieve.

ie, The 2nd query should work as if it was stated where country = India AND Price  = $100 (ie only IF both are true), return the name of all products that match this criteria (this will reveal alternative products at this price point in this country).
Repeat this search approach to show all products where country= Russia and price= $200 etc.

The first query should produce set of conditions and the 2nd query should loop through each of those conditions and produce the result.
The country and price combinations will differ and should not be defined statically at any point.

I have seen a few different approaches including WITH, CTE and subqueries but have struggled to do this correctly.
Part of the problem I am having is that my condition for the 2nd query is a combination of the results of the 1st query.

Any help with this is really appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a cursor that will run on the first query, will keep the 2 results in 2 local variables in every iteration and then will run the second query with those variables.